# Arrange numbers 2 to 20 to the hexagons

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, visual

Arrange numbers 2 to 20 to the hexagons, with rules :

1. The difference between 2 connected hexagons (side by side) is more than 4
2. Numbers inside the yellow hexagons are prime numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be it

> [image]

Approach

> Fixing the Prime numbers did the trick. Rest fell in place with a few trials

Answer (score 5):

The answer is

> First row: 2 
>  Second row: 14 12 
>  Third row: 4 7 6 
>  Fourth row: 19 18 
>  Fifth row: 9 13 11 
>  Sixth row: 3 5 
>  Seventh row: 17 20 16 
>  Eighth row: 8 10 
>  Ninth row: 15

Full solution:

> 1. You start by noting that the three primes that border 9 must be 3, 17, 19. The location of **3** is then set since it must take the spot that borders 20.
>
>    Next, note that 5 must be in one of the two yellow hexagons that are furthest to the right, or else it would border 2 or 3. The **7** must then be directly below the 2, or else it would border either 3 or 5.
>
>    After that, note that the 11 must also be in one of the furthest two yellow hexagons, or else it would border 7 or 9. This fixes **13** as the one right below 7.
>
>    From there, you can deduce that **5** is to the right of 13, and **11** is the prime furthest right (since the other way would have 11 border 13).
>
>    And finishing off the primes, due to 13's location, the prime between 9 and 7 must be **19**, and the last yellow hexagon is where **17** is located.
>
>    Note that because 5,7,11,13 are all adjacent to a square and we already know the location of both 19 and 20, this square contains **18**.
>
>    From here, note that the only possible number above 18 left is **12**, and the only possible number above 19 is **14**.
>
>    Next, note that the only number left that can be above 9 is **4**.
>
>    Next, note that the only number left that can border 11,12,18 is **6**.
>
>    **16** must then be below 11, since otherwise it would border 20.
>
>    **15** must be below 20 or else it borders 16 or 17.
>
>    **8** must then be below 3 (or else it would border 5), and **10** takes the remaining spot.

Comment: Probably the ninth row that you've mentioned is a typo :)

Comment: Explanation incoming; currently writing out all of the logic